# react: Modifying a dictionary inside of a list

Tags: reactjs

I have a state object like

```
this.state = {
            newPerson: '',
            people: [{name:'Eric', update: false} , {name:'Rick', update:false}, {name:'Yoni', update:false}]
        };
```

I want to map over the list and be able to modify N object (ie - set status to be true).

I was thinking that I could map over the list of dictionaries by checking to see if the `name` matches N object's name, then "pop out" / delete the dictionary, modify it and then re-add it.

Is there a better way to do this? Especially following react's "functional" programming style by not modifying a object in space.

Comment: I think you want to use a for each loop and simply update N object as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can just map over your people list and modify (merge) only the one that matches the requirement (eg name in your example - it won't affect the original array). But the best way would be indexing your objects in collection and then using map function - you can have duplicated names at some point.

I know it's redux docs, but can help you with your problem - https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns